# How to apply IAM Auth to only one method of an API gateway path - SAM template

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam, aws-sam

I am currently creating a SAM template defining an AWS API gateway. I have a path `/example` which has 3 methods; GET, POST and OPTIONS. I want the POST method to have IAM authorisation but the others to be public with no authorisation. My SAM template currently looks like this:

```
Resources:
  ApiGatewayApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      Name: <API NAME>
      StageName: <Stage Name>
      Auth:
        ApiKeyRequired: false
        AddDefaultAuthorizerToCorsPreflight: false
        DefaultAuthorizer: AWS_IAM
        ResourcePolicy:
          CustomStatements: [
            {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                  "arn:aws:iam::...",
                ]
              },
              "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
              "Resource": "execute-api:/<Stage Name>/POST/example"
            }]
      Tags:
        <Key>: <Value>
      DefinitionBody:
        <Swagger definition>
```

This is however attaching IAM auth to all of the methods. How can I specify it to only be attached to one of the methods?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using authorizers in you Swagger definition? AWS supports [x-amazon-apigateway-auth](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-swagger-extensions-auth.html) and [x-amazon-apigateway-authorizer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-swagger-extensions-authorizer.html) keys for adding authorizers in individual endpoints via the Swagger definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @kaustubh-khavnekar mentioned in the comments the following is required:

1. Remove `DefaultAuthorizer: AWS_IAM` from the `Auth` section.
2. Add the following to the swagger definition for the IAM protected method endpoint

```
post:
  x-amazon-apigateway-auth:
    type : "AWS_IAM"
```

3. Add the following to the swagger definition for the unprotected method endpoint:

```
get:
  x-amazon-apigateway-auth:
    type : "NONE"
```